# Weblogic 10.3.5 & EJB 3 JNDI names

Tags: ejb-3.0, jndi, weblogic11g

Could someone tell me where I can find infos on the default JNDI naming for EJB 3 ?

Does Weblogic use portable JNDI names like Glassfish?

Can I find (like for Glassfish) a trace of EJB deployment with JNDI names used?

For example :

- an interface (Service) with only @Remote
- a bean (ServiceImpl) with only @Stateless implementing the interface
- everything packaged in an `.ear` file (service-application-1.0)

When deploying on Weblogic the only JNDI reference I see is:

```
service-application-1.0service-application-1.0_jarServiceImpl_Home
```

but I can't use that name with a context lookup. If I do

```
Service myService = (Service) context.lookup("service-application-1.0service-application-1.0_jarServiceImpl_Home");
```

it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.ejb.container.internal.StatelessEJBHomeImpl_1035_WLStub cannot be cast to com.tuto.Service
at com.tuto.TestEjb.main(TestEjb.java:24)
```

PS. With Glassfish it gives me

```
Portable jndi names for .... : java:global/service-application-1.0/service-application-ejb-1.0/ServiceImpl
```

And

```
Service myService = (Service) context.lookup("java:global/service-application-1.0/service-application-ejb-1.0/ServiceImpl");
```

is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, EJB 3.0 does not specify a standard JNDI naming and leave it up to the server vendor. You are right by quoting WL documentation about mappedName: "If you specify this attribute, the stateless session bean may not be portable". The drawback of mappedName attribute is that the global JNDI name will be default to mappedName#FullyQualifiedRemoteInterface. Since mappedName is an annotation within the source code, it makes your code non-portable. The preferred way is to keep vendor-specific behavior in vendor specific deployment descriptors, such as weblogic-ejb-jar.xml. This way, you also have the choice of specifying your own custom JNDI name without the predetermined format as mappedName#FullyQualifiedRemoteInterface.

EJB 3.1 made some efforts to standardize JNDI names at global,application, and module levels. Please see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/girgn/index.html

Comment: Ok, thanks.  But I don't find, in this case with wl 10.3.5, what's the vendor-specific jndi name of an ejb without any annotation nor deployment descriptors ?

Comment: @tweetysat: In the book "Oracle WebLogic Server" (written by Robert Patrick, Gregory Nyberg, and Philip Aston, with Josh Bregman and Paul Done)
Chapter 6: Building Enterprise JavaBeans in WebLogic Server
Page 194
"
WebLogic Server provides two options for mapping a session bean's remote business interfaces into the global JNDI tree. The mapping can be specified in the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor or the mappedName element of the @ Stateless or @ Stateful annotations can be used."
So  there is no default jndi name if you do not use mappedName or weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can try `context.lookup("ServiveImpl#com.Service");`, where `ServiveImpl` is the mapped name for bean & after `#` it should be fully qualified interface name.

Comment: Ok, I tried but not working.  My ejb is in package com.tuto.  So I tried context.lookup("ServiceImpl#com.tuto.Service).    ... didn't find subcontext ServiceImpl#com.....

Comment: @tweetysat Have you specified `mappedName` as `ServiceImpl` for bean. If there is a single remote interface for bean, then you can try `lookup("Service")`.

Comment: Yes, using mappedName, it's working.  If I put 'toto' I can find the jndi toto#com.tuto.Service  But it's not reponsding my question of what's the default jndi name without anything like mappedName ?  According to the documentation of wl, mappedName and name are NOT required.  And they even tell : "If you specify this attribute, the stateless session bean may not be portable."  So what's the default portable name ?